# noindex follow in Robots.txt

Tags: seo, search-engine, robots.txt, nofollow

I have a wordpress website which has been indexed in search engines.

I have edited Robots.txt to disallow certain directories and webpages from search index.

I only know how to use allow and disallow, but don't know how to use the follow and nofollow in Robots.txt file.

I read somewhere while Googling on this that I can have webpages that won't be indexed in Google but will be crawled for pageranks. This can be achieved by disallowing the webpages in Robots.txt and use follow for the webpages.

Please let me know how to use follow and nofollow in Robots.txt file.

Answer (score 1):

a.) The follow/no follow and index/no index rules are not for robots.txt (sets general site rules) but for an on-page meta-robots tag (sets the rules for this specific page)

[More info about Meta-Robots](http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html)

b.) Google won't crawl the Disallowed pages but it can index them on SERP (using info from inbound links or website directories like Dmoz).
Having said that, there is no PR value you can gain from this.

[More info about Googlebot's indexing behavior](http://www.incapsula.com/the-incapsula-blog/item/395-new-snippet-puts-googlebot-in-the-spotlight)

Answer (score 1):

Google actually does recognize the Noindex: directive inside robots.txt. Here's Matt Cutts talking about it: http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/google-noindex-behavior/

If you put "Disallow" in robots.txt for a page already in Google's index, you will usually find that the page stays in the index, like a ghost, stripped of its keywords. I suppose this is because they know they won't be crawling it, and they don't want the index containing bit-rot.  So they replace the page description with "A description for this result is not available because of this site's robots.txt – learn more."

So, the problem remains: How do we remove that link from Google since "Disallow" didn't work?  Typically, you'd want to use meta robots noindex on the page in question because Google will actually remove the page from the index if it sees this update, but with that Disallow directive in your robots file, they'll never know about it.

So you could remove that page's Disallow rule from robots.txt and add a meta robots noindex tag to the page's header, but now you've got to wait for Google to go back and look at a page you told them to forget about.

You could create a new link to it from your homepage in hopes that Google will get the hint, or you could avoid the whole thing by just adding that Noindex rule directly to the robots.txt file. In the post above, Matt says that this will result in the removal of the link.

Comment: Indeed, there was the opportunity of GoogleBot that allowed to use.

But seen on the GoogleBlog-News they will no longer support those (0,001% used) commands anymore from September 2019 on. So you should only use meta tags anymore for these on your page to be safe for the future.

Answer (score 0):

No you cant.
You can set which directories you want to block and which bots but you cant set nofollow by robots.txt
Use robots meta tag on the pages to set nofollow.